# Implementing a report generator based on user selection

Tags: jakarta-ee, report, birt, xsl-fo

I want to design a Java EE website which can generate a custom report in pdf and rtf formats.

I found that BIRT Report Design tool helps to design the report. But what I want is to provide user the flexibility of choosing the chapters and parameters(like time interval, area, etc. ) by the users and on the basis of chapters and subchapters selected, the report is generated.

I wanted to know whether BIRT supports this flexibility or there are other tools or frameworks that can help me do this. Any resources or suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create parameterized reports with BIRT that allow the user to select or enter values.  There are also cascading parameter groups to allow you to have several levels of parameters for the user to select from.  From what I'm understanding with your question, that should allow you to do what you're wanting.

Hope this helps.